# I want to make my text include my max win value in pygame text but I ran out of arguments how should I do this?

Tags: python, pygame

So right now the code is only rendering COOKIES: [number]

I want it to show COOKIES : [number] / [winValue]

[number] is score counted per clicks on image.

[winValue] is the goal must hit to win

but I ran out of argument in my text render.

```
ERROR:
text = font.render('COOKIES : ' + str(score), True, BLACK, WHITE,winValue) #renders counter
TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

```
winValue = random.randint(10,100)

text = font.render('COOKIES : ' + str(score), True, BLACK, WHITE) #renders counter
```

What should I do to include my winValue?
Sorry I couldn't include the entire code here as it would be too long for stackoverflow to accept and sorry for the badly worded question as English isn't my first language.

Comment: What does "ran out of arguments" mean? I've never heard this term before.

Comment: Put it another way, I see what you're working with and what your desired output is, but I simply can't see what's preventing you from getting it. Everything is all there. Just append the other stuff to the string.

Comment: Error:
text = font.render('COOKIES : ' + str(score), True, BLACK, WHITE,winValue) #renders counter
TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)

Comment: Don't just randomly pass another argument. Append it to the string in the first argument. You had no problem doing that with `score`...

Comment: Also, add the attempt and exception into the question using the edit button.

Comment: I tried to simply the code down as much as possible because I couldn't show what is happening without showing the entire code but I guess I failed.

Comment: Oh no, your code was fine. Now that you added the problematic attempt, the question is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display 'COOKIES: score / winValue' then just do

```
text = font.render('COOKIES : ' + str(score) + '/' + str(winValue), True, BLACK, WHITE)
```